# Automatically build laravel pagination object

Tags: php, laravel

in my app each time I retrieve paginated results from the database I have to do somethig like this:

```
$posts = Post::latest()->with(['category','user'])->paginate($request->input('paginate', 6));

        $posts = 
        [
            'data' => $posts,
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $posts->total(),
                'per_page' =>$posts->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $posts->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $posts->lastPage(),
                'from' => $posts->firstItem(),
                'to' => $posts->lastItem()
            ] 
        ];
```

As you  see I first retrieve the results from database and then I have to manually create the paginated data array, always doing the same seems bad and tedious to me honestly, I was wondering if there is a laravel magic method to automatically build the pagination payload array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eloquent: API Resources "https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources"

You should create a resource: `php artisan make:resource PostCollection`

and you should change method `toArray($request)` for something like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'pagination' => [
            'total' => $this->total(),
            'per_page' =>$this->perPage(),
            'current_page' => $this->currentPage(),
            'last_page' => $this->lastPage(),
            'from' => $this->firstItem(),
            'to' => $this->lastItem()
        ]
    ];
}
```

Now when you want to paginate your Model you just do it like this:

```
//Get posts
$posts = Post::latest()->with(['category','user'])
    ->paginate($request->input('paginate', 6)));

//Use your resource (Collection)
$postsPaginate = new PostCollection($posts);

//Return your resource
return $porstsPaginate;
```